# Filtering mysql database with php when using multi checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to coding and trying to build an e-commerce site. I have all my products in a database and have linked it to my webpage using php while loop but i am trying to figure out how to filter the data displayed by using check boxes so the user can filter by colour, price, brand etc. The code I currently have is as follows:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">

  <form method="post">

   <div class="col-md-4 checkbox form-group">
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox" value="">
      Urban Outfitters
    </label>
    <label>
     <input type="checkbox" value="">
      Topman
    </label>
   </div>

  <div class="col-md-4 checkbox form-group">
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
     Nike
   </label>
   <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="">
    Topman
   </label>
  </div>


 </div>

 </form>

     <?php 

       $query = "SELECT image, retailer, brand, name, price, sale_price, saving, percentage, link, colour, category FROM mensproducts WHERE category='Accessories'";

   if ($result=mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

   // output data 

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<div class='col-md-3'> 
            <table class='product table-responsive'>
            <tr><td class='productImage'><a href=".$row["link"]." target='_blank'><img src='".$row["image"]."'/></a></td></tr>
            <tr><td class='retailer'>".$row["retailer"]."</td></tr> 
            <tr><td class='brand'>".$row["brand"]."</td></tr>  
            <tr><td class='desc'>".$row["name"]."</td></tr>  
            <tr><td class='price'><span style='color:red;text-decoration:line-through'>£".$row["price"]."</span>   £".$row["sale_price"]."</td></tr>  
            <tr><td class='productLink'><a class='btn btn-primary btn-block' href=".$row["link"]." target='_blank' role='button'>Buy Now</a></td></tr> 
            </table>
          </div>";

    }

    } else {

       echo "It failed!";

    }

 ?>

</div>
```

Comment: your checkboxes need named attributes and bearing the same name if you're going to want to let them use the same ones in the query and treat them as an array. I.e.: `name="check[]"`.

Comment: use FROM mensproducts WHERE category='Accessories' and ...

Comment: "I am fairly new to coding and trying to build an e-commerce site." While everyone has to get a start somewhere, building an e-commerce site as your first project is like learning to sail by going across the ocean in a tiny boat. I'd *strongly* encourage you to evaluate existing solutions like [Magento](https://magento.com) before getting too married to this code base.

Comment: This is a hugely ambitious project for a beginner, but there are lots of tutorials covering the various aspects of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First name your checkboxes:
`<input type="checkbox" name="nike" value="">`
and
`<input type="checkbox" name="topman" value="">`
Then add check the parameters and modify the query:

```
if(($_POST["nike"] && $_POST["topman"]) || (!$_POST["nike"] && !$_POST["topman"])) {
   $query = "SELECT image, retailer, brand, name, price, sale_price, saving, percentage, link, colour, category FROM mensproducts WHERE category='Accessories'";
} elseif($_POST["nike"]) {
   $query = "SELECT image, retailer, brand, name, price, sale_price, saving, percentage, link, colour, category FROM mensproducts WHERE category='Accessories' AND mark='nike'";
} else {
   $query = "SELECT image, retailer, brand, name, price, sale_price, saving, percentage, link, colour, category FROM mensproducts WHERE category='Accessories' AND mark='topman'";
}
```

Just replace mark with the SQL column of the mark.

Comment: When formatting code, just indent by four spaces or use the `{}` button to do it for you. This looks all messed up.